# What components of a url are rewritten with apache mod_proxy in a Location tag?

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

```
<Location /partA>
    ProxyPass https://example.com/partB
    ProxyPassReverse https://example.com/partB
</Location>
```

What URLs are called on the remote server?

http://example.net/testA/partC is called. Is the URL called on the remote server

- https://example.com/partB/partC

Or the alternatives

- https://example.com/partB/partA/partC

What parts of the URL are replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass) say it's the first

> https://example.com/partB/partC

The location is dropped.